# Issue regarding using power supply for WD MY BOOK HDD

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-supply

My original power adapter of WD MY BOOK HDD, which is damaged, has the following specifications:

Input: 100-240V  Output: 12V 1.5A (center pin positive)

[image: Adapter]

I want to use the adapter below which has the same output but different input.

Input: 90-270V  Output: 12V 1.5A (center pin positive)

[image: New Adapter]

Can it harm my HDD or is it 100% safe to use it?

Comment: We have lots of questions about using other adapters, but I didn't spot another one that asked specifically about the input voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new adapter should work just fine.  Both outputs match (both in voltage and amperage) on the two power supplies.  The difference in input voltage just means that the replacement adapter can work with a wider range of wall voltages.

Something that you should also keep in mind is the polarity.  In this case, both of these power supplies have the same polarity diagrams as well (see below picture).

[image]